# Looking for website examples for a drag and drop style widget

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I'm designing a site and they want me to add the functionality to drag and drop different data to be displayed to the client in different ways. For example, bar charts or line charts. I'm having trouble visualizing a good way to incorporate this to make it look nice and not cheesy. Below I have images to show the basic idea of what I mean.

[image: BasicExample]

Then you should be able to drag options from the side to display data.

[image]

The struggle really comes from the website though. Because it is an older looking site, its hard to find a good way to design something like this. Hence way I'm looking for examples. So far I'm unable to find anything good. Maybe my search terms are incorrect. Anyways, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Google Analytics, look at the 'Customization → Dashboards' panel where you can do exactly that, add widgets and drag them around to reconfigure the page.

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1068218